# Some images are not uploading to the website through my php code

Tags: php, html, image-upload

So I am trying to upload images and i am given this message for some images mostly those taken by my phone's camera or those that are screenshot through "snipping tool" the error im given is "Error: Error in uploading file. Please try again." any ideas what is wrong with my code?

```html
if ($_POST && !empty($_FILES))
    {
     $formOk = true;

     //Assign Variables
     $path = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
     $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","alaa","registration_database");
     $sql = "select max(id) as maximum from ads";
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      
      }
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     
     
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $id = $row['maximum'];
     $id++;
     $parts = explode(".", $name);
     $targetFile = "uploads/".$id.".".$parts[sizeof($parts)-1];
     
     
     if ($_FILES['image']['error'] || !is_uploaded_file($path)) {
      $formOk = false;
      echo "Error: Error in uploading file. Please try again.";
     }

     //check file extension
     if ($formOk && !in_array($type, array('image/png','image/PNG', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg','image/JPG', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif'))) {
      $formOk = false;
      echo "Error: Unsupported file extension. Supported extensions are JPG / PNG.";
     }
     // check for file size.
     if ($formOk && filesize($path) > 2097152) {
      $formOk = false;
      echo "Error: File size must be less than 2 MB.";
     }

     if ($formOk) {
      // read file contents
      //$targetFile = file_get_contents($path);
      if(move_uploaded_file($path,$targetFile)){
       echo "image uploaded";
      } else {
       echo "Error while uploading";
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Please format the code so it's readable. Also, why did you add a JavaScript snippet? It doesn't make a sense since it's not JavaScript.

Comment: Can you put `print_r($_FILES['image']['error']);` before line with `if ($_FILES['image']['error']...` and tell us what error code do you get?

Comment: To your question - It's you who's writing that error message, so you know what's wrong. Just check if `$_FILES['image']['error']` contains non-zero value (and if yes then what) or `is_uploaded_file` is returning `false`. Then you'll know more. Consult possible error values with the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: @alex_edev i got this "2Error: Error in uploading file. Please try again. "

Comment: 2 stands for "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.". Thus you need to make changes to your html code if you don't want this error to happen again or you may just put `$_FILES['image']['error']  && $_FILES['image']['error'] != 2` instead of `$_FILES['image']['error']` if you'd like to skip this error. But the latter is not a good practice though. You may read about the rest error codes in the manual. See the link above in Dawid's comment.